# Read keypress using JScript

Tags: keypress, wsh, jscript

I am trying to do a simple JScript using the Windows Script Host (outside any browser, was my intent) to read users keypresses, but can't find a way to do what amounts to:

```
function tap(e) {
    ...code...
}
document.onkeypress = tap;
```

I'm no Windows systems programming guy (but a seasoned programmer) so I'm unfamiliar with ActiveX gadgets and services and the like. Doesn't WScript or WSShell provide a way to open a window (instead of the 'document')?

Or am I forced to run this from a browser to make it work? Seems overkill...

Comment: Neither am I a Windows systems guy, but do you know whether or not WSH provides a `document` interface?

Comment: I'm far from an expert in WSH, but http://www.visualbasicscript.com/KeyPressed-for-WSH-or-something-similar-m61097.aspx suggests that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Scripting Host doesn't provide any UI, well, not a GUI at least.

If you use `CScript.exe` then you can use StdIn, StdOut, etc. See [Wscript.StdIn.Read method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w5tbs5z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

These are most of the objects available for Windows Scripting Host: [main WSH objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74hyyw0%28VS.85%29.aspx), the dictionary and FileSystem objects come in handy: [Dictionary and FileSystem objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bstcxhf7%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

But if you want a GUI, then you can run an HTA file in MSHTA.exe and use HTML/CSS/JavaScript to handle your UI needs and still use the WSH objects.

Overkill? Well, list what you want from your UI. Now, you'd have to provide a mechanism for accessing all those features. And your example code shows you'd want to do it in a HTML-DOM-via-JavaScript-like manner. So, you'd need an HTML parser and DOM support. Looks like you want access to most of what a browser provides at that point.

Comment: Thanks, HTA was the missing link. It provides an environment where JScripting and ActiveX control of Applications meets GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var tap = function (e) {
  ...code...
}

document.onkeypress = tap;
```

Comment: Your code does about the same, only replacing a function declaration with a function expression...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Windows Script Host provides an API for keyboard hooks.  The most reliable way to do this may be to create a COM component that [implements a keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx) (in C#/C++, for example) and use an instance of that object in JScript as needed.